# Convert to JSON data to custom string using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSon out put like this

```
[{"label":"Alabama"},{"label":"Alaska"},{"label":"Arizona"},...etc]
```

I want to get each of the state names like this

```
["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona",...etc]
```

Here is my attempt to convert json to custom string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var res = [{ "label": "Alabama" }, { "label": "Alaska" }, { "label": "Arizona" }];
var out = $.parseJSON(res);
alert(out);
});
</script>
```

The above doesn’t seem to be working, Please help me some one.

Comment: The purpose of `$.parseJSON` is to parse a JSON string into a Javascript object.  For example, `$.parseJSON('[1, 2, 3]')`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var meow = [];

$.each(out, function(l, i){
    meow.push(i);
});
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in javascript.  It should be `var somethingOtherThanNew = []`

Comment: Read even more carefully

Comment: Woah there, I actually feel kinda silly right now. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```
var res = [{"label":"Alabama"},{"label":"Alaska"},{"label":"Arizona"}];
var states = x.map(function(o){
    return o.label;
});
```

**or Lo-dash**

```
var states = _.map(res , 'label');
```

[jQuery#map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), since you're already using that and it should address browser issues

```
var states = jQuery.map( res , function( o, i ) {
  return o.label;
});
```

Comment: It's important to note that `Array.map` is not available in IE8 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

`res` is already JavaScript data structures.  Using `$.parseJSON` is redundant and will result in an error.  Remove that line.

As for getting the array elements:

```
states = res.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.label;
});
```

Or if you're using Underscore.js, `_.pluck(res, "label")`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/), all you'd need to do is:

```
_.values(res);
```

or

```
_.map(res, 'label');
```

No need to worry about browser the compatibility issues with something like `Array.map`.